# Como inserir vários dados de uma só vez no banco de dados vindo de vários inputs com o mesmo nome?

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, input, tabela-html

Estou gerando linhas através de javascript para que o usuário cadastre várias informações de uma só vez na tabela. Quando envio a requisição o banco só grava um registro e preciso que pegue todas as linhas preenchidas e grave no banco. Utilizo laravel 5.8.

Código html no blade =>

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('store.peps') }}" class="form">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="row mt-3" style="border: 1px solid #FFF;">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row form-group mt-2">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                            <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th width="05%" class="text-uppercase text-center">remover linha
                                                </th>
                                                <th width="15%" class="text-uppercase text-center">área</th>
                                                <th width="10%" class="text-uppercase text-center">equipamento</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="dynamicDiv">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="5%" class="text-center">
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="removeRow"
                                                       class="btn btn-danger">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-times fa-md"></i></a></td>
                                                <td width="15%" class="text-uppercase text-center">
                                                    <input type="text" name="ds_area[]">
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="10%" class="text-uppercase text-center">
                                                    <input type="text" name="nr_equipamento[]" style="width: 50%;">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mt-2 mb-2">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addRow"
                                       class="btn btn-block btn-warning text-uppercase">Adicionar equipamento</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success text-uppercase">Salvar
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

javascript =>

```
$(function () {
        var scntDiv = $("#dynamicDiv");

        $(document).on('click', '#addRow', function () {
            $('<tr>' +
                '<td width="5%" class="text-center">' +
                '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="removeRow" class="btn btn-danger">' +
                '<i class="fas fa-times fa-md"></i></a>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td width="15%" class="text-uppercase text-center">' +
                '<input type="text" name="ds_area[]">' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td width="10%" class="text-uppercase text-center">' +
                '<input type="text" name="nr_equipamento[]" style="width: 50%;">' +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            return false;
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Controller PepController@store =>

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $codMonitoramento = ItensMonitoramento::where('cd_item_monitoramento', '>', 0)->pluck('cd_item_monitoramento')->max() + 1;

    $itensMonitoramentos = new ItensMonitoramento();

    $itensMonitoramentos->cd_item_monitoramento = $codMonitoramento;
    $itensMonitoramentos->ds_area = array($request['ds_area']);
    $itensMonitoramentos->nr_equipamento = array($request['nr_equipamento']);

    $request->flash();
    $itensMonitoramentos->save();

    if($itensMonitoramentos){
        return redirect()->route('list.monitoramentos')->with('success', 'Área e equipamentos cadastrados com sucesso!');
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('list.monitoramentos')->with('error', 'Erro ao cadastrar!');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o atributo `name` dos inputs está definido como um array, para cada área e equipamento adicionado dinamicamente será criado uma nova posição no array com os novos valores definidos pelo usuário.

Então, na controller precisaremos organizar os valores para utilizar a função `createMany`.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $codMonitoramento = ItensMonitoramento::where('cd_item_monitoramento', '>', 0)->pluck('cd_item_monitoramento')->max() + 1;

    $data = []; // Criando um array vazio
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request['ds_area']); $i++) {
        $data[] = [
            'cd_item_monitoramento' => $codMonitoramento, 
            'ds_area' => $request['ds_area'][$i],
            'nr_equipamento' => $request['nr_equipamento'][$i]
        ]; // Populando cada posição do array com um array contendo os valores a serem persistidos
    }        

    $request->flash();

    try {
         DB::table('tab_itens_monitoramentos')->insert($data);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->route('list.monitoramentos')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }

    return redirect()->route('list.monitoramentos')->with('success', 'Área e equipamentos cadastrados com sucesso!');
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo, dá um erro falando que o metodo createMany não pode ser usado. Isso por que não estou usando nenhum tipo de relacionamento.

Comment: Você pode colar o erro que está aparecendo?

Comment: Consegui Victor mas tive que alterar seu código.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com a edição que sugeriu, mas era para a função `createMany` funcionar também, pois utilizo ela sem problemas em meus projetos laravel. Mas cada projeto é um projeto, certo?! Fico feliz em ter te ajudado!